# How to create an optdef_prop with ppx syntax in js_of_ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

How can I create an object property of type `Js.optdef_prop` with the PPX syntax in js_of_ocaml?

I tried something like follow but with no success:

```
type t = <foo: Js.js_string Js.t Js.optdef_prop> Js.t
...
(object%js
  val foo = Js.Optdef (Js.string "bar")
end :> t)
```

The [documentation](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.8.4/api/Ppx_js) only talks about `Js.readonly_prop` and `Js.prop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember implementing, and I doubt it was added later.

IIRC, One of the reason was that there was no easy syntax to use, but I could have just used an attribute. Another was that it didn't seem that useful at the time, but I guess I was wrong. :)

Please make a feature request on the bug tracker.